# php array not setting new key and value

Tags: php

I have a class with two arrays as members.
$member_albums and $member_photos.

As part of the initialization I am taking data from both and building
urls for each photo to be added as a value in the member photos array.
This is being done by a method within the class.
However, I cannot seem to add values or even change existing ones.
Help?

Here is the method -

```
private function build_urls() {

    // If data was retrieved without errors
    if ($this->member_albums && $this->member_photos) {

        // If user has albums
        if ($this->member_albums['Count'] > 0) {

            // for number of albums
            for ($x = 0; $x < $this->member_albums['Count']; $x++) {

                // current album ID
                $curr_AlbumId = $this->member_albums['Items'][$x][MEMBER_ALBUM_ID]['S'];

                // if current album contains photos
                if ($this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId]['Count'] > 0) {

                    // for number of photos in current album 
                    for ($y = 0; $y < $this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId]['Count']; $y++) {

                        // add url key and value to this photo item array                                                                                   
                        $this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId]['Items'][$y]['url'] = array('S' =>
                        'http://www.example/somephoto.jpg');
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Adding example of arrays data structure.

```
$member_albums -
[Count] => 1 [Items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Timestamp] => Array ( [N] => 468839229.371792 ) [Year] => Array ( [N] => 0 ) [UserId] => Array ( [S] => A05737C7-7D63-4EA8-8316-9D274DAE1BD0 ) [AlbumId] => Array ( [S] => album_3 ) ) 


$member_photos -
[Count] => 9 [Items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ShotId] => Array ( [S] => Photo4 ) [AlbumId] => Array ( [S] => album_3 ) [UserId] => Array ( [S] => A05737C7-7D63-4EA8-8316-9D274DAE1BD0 ) [Year] => Array ( [N] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: Can you show exerts of what each of those arrays looks like?

Comment: Yes, how do we know `member_albums['Count']` is greater than 0?

Comment: Also, you'll probably have more understandable and easier code using `foreach()`.

Comment: The data is a dynamoDB query result. Count is 0 or greater, number of arrays in the array. The members_photo array has nine inner arrays, thus count = 9. I only copied part of this array as an example.

Comment: In the method I'm trying to add a new key 'url' with a value into the members_photo inner arrays (individual photo item data), but no success.

Comment: Where is the constant MEMBER_ALBUM_ID declared?

Comment: All consts are declared in constants.php.
All the values are ok, the only thing that does not work as I expect is the line $this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId]['Items'][$y]['url'] = array('S' =>
                        'http://www.example/somephoto.jpg');