# Best way to copy an Object's protected member's data into an array

Tags: php

*** Edited my question after the underlining issue was determined.

Many thanks to choz who helped to diagnose the issue***

*** Description ***
I have a class with two members that hold album data and photos data correspondingly.
In the constructor I populate them with data pulled from a DB query.
These queries return an Object with an array that is a protected member of the Object.

I was trying to add a new key and value into the Object holding a associative array mistakenly treating it as a mere array.
These new key and value were not being set. Presumably because the Object's array member is protected.
See var dump below, where the Object dump begins with:
["data":protected].
Is this the issue? And if so, how is the best way to create my own copies that I can manipulate freely?

```
/****** Class  Memebers ********/ 
//Object with array of associative album arrays.
//Each inner album array is defined by unique key ='albumID'.
private $member_albums; 


//array of objects holding associative photo arrays.
//Each inner photo array is defined by unique key ='albumID'.
private $member_photos;
```

This is the method used to add key and value -

```
/*
* For each photo in each album, we will add a new key and value.  
* key = 'img_url', value is an array with structure of 
* ['S']['{url pointing to this photo in storage}'] where 'S' is the 
* key (representing a string value) and value is the url string.  
*/
private function add_Photo_Url_To_Photos_Data_Array(){

  // If data was retrieved from DB without errors
  // because query fail returns false.
  if( $this->member_albums && $this->member_photos){

    // If user has albums - because 'Count' is always 0 or
    // greater, representing the number of inner arrays
    if($this->member_albums['Count'] > 0 ){ 

        // For number of albums
        foreach ($this->member_albums['Items'] as $albumArr) {

            // Current album ID 
            $curr_AlbumId = $albumArr['albumID']['S'];                  

            // If current album contains photos
            if( $this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId]['Count'] > 0){                                              

                // For each photo in this album
                foreach( $this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId]['Items'] as &$photosArr) {

                    // method that creates a url from photo data- returns string url                                                                                    
                    $url = $this->build_Photo_Url($photosArr, $curr_AlbumId);                                                       

                    // Insert new key = 'img_url' and value into the array.                                                                                 
                    // new value is itself an array with key ['S']  
                    // signifying a string and value $url   
                    $photosArr['img_url'] = array('S' =>
                    $url);

                    // this echo shows key and value were added
                    // correctly into $photosArr
                    echo ' <br>Img URL = ' . $photosArr['img_url']['S'];                                                            
                }                   
            }                                   
        }
    }
}
```

But if I try and echo 'img_url' from $this->member_photos array item, it does not exist.

Thanks.

*** EDIT 3 ****
Adding var_dump($this->member_albums) and var_dump($this->member_photos)

**var_dump($this->member_albums)**

```
object(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model)#88 (2) { 
["structure":protected]=> NULL ["data":protected]=> array(3) { 
    ["Count"]=> int(2) 
    ["Items"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> array(7) { 
            ["PlaceLong"]=> array(1) { ["N"]=> string(1) "0" } 
            ["AlbumId"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(7) "album_1" } 
            ["Title"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(5) "Test1" } 
            ["UserId"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(36) "810725E5-D235-43F7-AA50-4CCDACD6AB36" } 
            ["Year"]=> array(1) { ["N"]=> string(1) "0" } 
            ["PlaceLat"]=> array(1) { ["N"]=> string(1) "0" } 
            ["Timestamp"]=> array(1) { ["N"]=> string(16) "472572846.470462" } 
        }
```

**var_dump($this->member_photos)**

```
array(2) { 
["album_1"]=> object(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model)#89 (2) { 
["structure":protected]=> NULL ["data":protected]=> array(3) { 
    ["Count"]=> int(5) 
    ["Items"]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> array(8) { 
            ["ShotId"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(6) "Photo2" } 
            ["AlbumId"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(7) "album_1" } 
            ["UserId"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(16) "1111-11111-11111" } 
            ["Year"]=> array(1) { ["N"]=> string(1) "0" } 
            ["Discovery"]=> array(1) { ["N"]=> string(1) "0" } 
            ["Timpstamp"]=> array(1) { ["N"]=> string(14) "472572840.3845" } 
            ["ExtractedPhotoId"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(32) "Photo2_0-0-746-0-0-1000-746-1000" } 
            ["ManualEdit"]=> array(1) { ["N"]=> string(1) "0" } 
        }
```

Comment: can you share the structure of the DB results?

Comment: On the last `echo` after `$photosArr['img_url'] = array('S' => $url);`. What's the result?

Comment: Img URL = {correct http address of storage}/{correct bucket name}/{correct user id}/album_1/{correct file name}

Comment: Wait, I don't get your question.. Which part is going wrong again? And what's your expected result?

Comment: I believe it's because your aren't looping member_albums by reference .. So this line `foreach ($this->member_albums['Items'] as $albumArr) {` should be `foreach ($this->member_albums['Items'] as &$albumArr) {`

Comment: I'm failing to add a new key and value into each inner array (of parent member_photos array of arrays).

Comment: No, its not &$albumArr.. This array is only used to read data from, no setting of data into it.. The photos array which I am trying to set data into, is passed by reference...

Comment: Can you please add more details like which part is failing? How do you know it's failing? What's the current result? And what's the expected result?.. IF I get your question correctly, when you iterate `$this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId]['Items']` with foreach and set url into each of items, they are not setting, Are they?

Comment: choz - yes, you are correct. setting new key and value for each $this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId]['Items'] fails..
As mentioned in a comment above, the echo within the method shows the key and value correct.
But if I later echo $this->member_photos['album_1']['Items'][0]['img_url']['S'] I get zilch...

Comment: Not sure why it's not working now, but out of curiosity - did you try to drop the foreach, use a regular for (i=0...;i++) and put the new key-value in the array member?  `$this->member_photos[$curr_albumID]['Items'][i]['img_url'] = array('S' => $url);`

Comment: oshnaps - :) yep. Tried this to make sure no error was with foreach.. Same problem and results..

choz - tried it, does not work at all, echo in method returns - "Img URL = "

Comment: Really frustrating.. I've wasted a lot of time on this thing, and can't figure out whats going wrong.. I'm new to PHP and worried that I'm missing something obvious..

Comment: Doesn't seem obvious. Where is it "later" where you try to retrieve the url value?

Comment: One more try, how about `$photosArr['img_url']['S'][] = $url;`. If that doesn't work, please provide `var_dump($url)`. I am trying your code asap.

Comment: Thanks..
Didn't work, 

var_dump($url) is -
string(134) "https://s3.amazonaws.com//{bucket name}/11111-11111-11111/album_1/Photo2_inner_0-0-746-0-0-1000-746-1000.jpg"

Comment: Can you post the result of `var_dump($this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId]`, by the end of your code?.

Comment: oshanps - "Later" is in a simple printme method I wrote to show all values of the arrays. All key\value pairs are there, just no the ones I tired to add in the above method.

Comment: choz - var_dump($this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId] is:

object(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model)#89 (2) { ["structure":protected]=> NULL ["data":protected]=> array(3) { ["Count"]=> int(5) ["Items"]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(8) { ["ShotId"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(6) "Photo2" } ["AlbumId"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(7) "album_1" } ["UserId"]=> array(1) { ["S"]=> string(36) "11111-11111-11111" } ["Year"]=> array(1) { ["N"]=> string(1) "0" } .... and the other photos data

Comment: Nvm, I got this. I will post this soon.

Comment: Could the array for some reason be write protected?
Even if i try to change an existing key\value like so -
$this->member_photos['album_1']['Items'][0]['UserId]['S'] = '2222-22222-22222' the value remains the same and will not get '2222-22222-22222'.

Comment: Thanks choz, much much much appreciated..

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious but, from your DB query example "Photos data" I can't find a key (at the first level) which could be responding to `$curr_AlbumId` in your `foreach ($this->member_photos[$curr_AlbumId]['Items'] as &$photosArr)`.

Comment: Don't mind of my previous comment: I just realized that "Photos data" was probalby not the whole structure but just the `AlbumId` part of it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php array not setting new key and value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426501/php-array-not-setting-new-key-and-value)

Comment: Try treat it as an object like `$this->member_albums->Items`.

Comment: The issue is this. In my class I am populating two members of data from a DB query. This query returns an Object with protected data. At start, I was not aware of this and could not understand why I could not edit or add data to this Object. I mistakenly treated it as a php array. What I am asking, is what is the best way to create an actual array, with the same data that the object holds, so I can add and edit data freely.

Comment: :) No, as you can see in the var_dump, $this->member_photos is an Object with an array of arrays as a protected member.
I want to either find a way to manipulate data of this member of Object, or if this cannot be done, learn how best to copy this array of arrays so I can then manipulate the data on a non-Object standard php array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Jay, after reading all the comments and doing basic search on the `Model` you're using, your object supports `toArray()` function which will return data in an array format without `protected` member.

Here's the reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-models.html

First, try to run `var_dump(get_class_methods($this->member_albums)));` to see what kind of methods it will return. I'm sure there is a built-in `toArray()` function mainly because it's a response so they would have made it easy for you to extract and manipulate your data.

Try the `var_dump()` first, then attempt doing the following `$clearArr = $this->member_albums->toArray();` and print_r/var_dump `$clearArr`, it should result to standard multidimensional array.